# How can I change elements position in a JS list?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, htmlelements

I was trying to sort (based on dates) the elements in an array using the insertion sort algorithm, I think the problem is due to the nature of the element in the list, because when it comes to `var x = A[i]` or (outside the while) `A[j + 1] = x` the programme crashes and the Chrome console gives back

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set an indexed property on HTMLCollection: Indexed property setter is not supported.
```

I'm new to JS so don't be ruthless to me
Here's my code:

```
function insertion_sort(A) {
        var len = A.length;
        var i = 1;
        while (i < len) {
            var x = A[i];
            var j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && dayjs(A[j].querySelector('span').innerText).format('YYYY-MM-DD') > dayjs(x.querySelector('span').innerText).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
                A[j + 1] = A[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            A[j + 1] = x;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        console.log(A);
    }
    
    let posts = [];
    
    posts = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
    
    insertion_sort(posts);
```

Comment: if you want to sort based on dates consider using `date-fns`

Comment: @Napstar I cannot change my library unfortunately I have to you dayjs

Comment: You are trying to sort the element positions on the page?

Comment: HtmlCollection is not an array. You can convert it to an array with `Array.from(posts)`

Comment: @epascarello yes I am

Comment: @epascarello I tried the syntax you wrote, but it doesn't work, it gives me back the same error